# Exception thrown on bitmap declaration under weird circumstances

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I encountered this problem and through much frustration isolated it to this. 
When I drag a file on my exe from another folder, a bitmap declaration that has nothing to with the command line arguments throws an exception "System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid".

This does not happen when:

1. The file is dragged from the same folder as exe
2. The file is dragged on a shortcut of the exe

Here is the minimum code that produces this error:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim logo As New Bitmap("logo.png")  'an image in the same dir as exe
            Me.BackgroundImage = logo
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Exception: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Unless that file is local to the executable, you will have to provide the full path of that file.

Comment: @LarsTech Yes, it's local. Edited to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide just a file name then it is assumed that that file resides in the current directory.  The current directory is not always the same at startup and it can change while an application is running too.

I'm guessing that that file is in the same folder as your EXE.  In that case, when the code works the current directory must be the application folder and in cases where it fails the current directory must be some other folder.

We often see similar issues when `Process.Start` is used run a game.  Many games do as you have and assume that the current directory is the application folder.  If you run the game from the commandline or the like then it will be.  If you use `Process.Start` to run the game from code, the new process will actually inherit the current directory of your application and that sort of code will fail.

The solution is to ALWAYS be explicit about the path of a file.  If you want to open a file that is in your application folder then specify exactly that:

```
Dim logo As New Bitmap(IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "logo.png"))
```

That code doesn't rely on the current directory being a specific folder so will be unaffected if it isn't.

Comment: Thanks. Your snippet fixes the problem. But no matter where I drag the file from, `Application.StartupPath` is always the same thing.

Comment: Of course `Application.StartupPath` is the same every time. That's the whole point. It's the current directory that changes and using `Application.StartupPath` means that the current directory is irrelevant. Now, if my answer has fixed the issue then please accept it

Comment: @LarsTech, it's not demanding at all. I'm simply asking you to use this site properly. I don't much care about the reputation points. What I care about is the fact that others can see without opening this thread that your question has already been answered. If you think it's demanding that I politely ask you to do what you should have done already without prompting in order to help everyone then this site may not be for you.